# changing warning message in datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have datatable and i have advance search using two combo box my problem is if i search some data and the data doesnt exist it shows warning like this *DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1*. Now i want to change the warning like *no job exist*. Help me pls. im just student sorry for my english

this my code in my search.php

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <form id="myForm" class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Experience</label>
            <select id="experience" class="form-control" name="exp">
              <option disabled selected>Select Experience</option>
              <?php
              $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(experience) FROM job_post WHERE experience is not null";
              $result=$conn->query($sql);
              if ($result->num_rows>0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  echo "<option value='".$row['experience']."'>".$row['experience']."</option>";
                }
              }
              ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Qualification</label>
            <select id="qualification" class="form-control" name="qua">
              <option disabled selected>Qualification</option>
              <?php
              $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(qualification) FROM job_post WHERE qualification is not null";
              $result=$conn->query($sql);
              if ($result->num_rows>0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  echo "<option value='".$row['qualification']."'>".$row['qualification']."</option>";
                }
              }
              ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <button id="" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5%;">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="myTable" class="table" style="width: 1190px;">
          <thead>
            <th>Job Name</th>
            <th>Job Description</th>
            <th>Minimum Salary</th>
            <th>Maximum Salary</th>
            <th>Experience</th>
            <th>Qualification</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){

    var oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
      "autoWidth" : false,
      "ajax" : {
          "url" : "refresh_job_search.php",
          "dataSrc": "",
          "data" : function(d){
            d.experience = $("#experience").val();
            d.qualification = $("#qualification").val();
          }
      }
    });

    $("#myForm").on("submit", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      oTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
    });



  });
</script>
```

and this is my refresh_job_search.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("db.php");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM job_post";

if (!empty($_GET['experience'])) {
    $sql = $sql." WHERE experience = '$_GET[experience]'";
}

if (!empty($_GET['qualification']) && !empty($_GET['experience'])) {
    $sql = $sql." AND qualification = '$_GET[qualification]'";
}else if(!empty($_GET['qualification'])){
    $sql = $sql." WHERE qualification = '$_GET[qualification]'";
}


$result=$conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows>0) {
  while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $json[] = array(
        0 => $row['jobtitle'],
        1 => $row['description'],
        2 => $row['minimumsalary'],
        3 => $row['maximumsalary'],
        4 => $row['experience'],
        5 => $row['qualification'],
        );
  }
  echo json_encode($json);
 }
```

Comment: You need to evaluate the data first before initializing the DataTables.

Comment: The dattable is already showing the data from database the problem is if i search data that doesnt exist in the database. It gives a warning . I want to have change that warning or show some message that data doesnt exist

Comment: Change your PHP query script to return empty json array matching the columns of your table if the result is 0. In that case, the DataTables error will not show.

Comment: can you tell me how ?